# Finding the relative path with javapackager -BlicenseFile=

Tags: java, javafx, javapackager

I'm having trouble understanding why

```
javapackager -deploy -native installer -BlicenseFile=license.rtf [...]
```

command will not find the file license.rtf.

The license.rtf file is in the root of the JAR. The packager builds the native installers when the -BlicenseFile argument is missing. But refuses when the argument is given. Can anyone help?

The application is JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
javapackager -deploy -native installer -srcfiles license.rtf -BlicenseFile=license.rtf [...]
```

if you really claim it is in the root directory,

the `-srcfiles` addition adds the licensefile to the temp directory that `javapackager` uses to bundle your binaries

Comment: Hi Elltz, thank you for your help. I found it's best to not put the license.rtf inside the app's jar; instead to put the app's jar and license file in the root -srcdir side by side.